# SQLite database handling with android application

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi i am going to create a `SQLite database` and insert records. but my database does not create.
following is the code. Cant understand why. trying this for a long time

If someone can help its a great help

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{


static final String dbName="MyDatabase";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
      super(context, dbName, null,33);    
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String qry = "CREATE TABLE DEPT(dept_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, deptName TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(qry);
}
}
```

I am calling the constructor like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    DatabaseHelper dp = new DatabaseHelper(this);



    Toast.makeText(this, "Finish Execution", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

}
}
```

Comment: Add portions of your stack trace to get better replies...

Answer (score 0):

create your database by using this sample 
http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/55.html